# How to make wildcard without double and float

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I want to make generic, that can contain only Number without decimal part (`Integer`,`Long`, `Char`, `Byte`, `Short`). Is it possible? I understand that `class Number` is `abstract`, so everybody can write own implementation of every kind of numbers. But now I talk only about Oracle implementations.

Comment: Can you be more clear with your question? Why do you need this other data type when you already have access to `Integer` and `Long`?

Comment: @JeremyKato I mean, that solution, which works only with standard Number classes pass for me

Comment: I suppose if you really wanted to make your own number type (perhaps `SuperLong` for massive numbers) you can write your own class that inherits from the `Number` class. So in short, yes, it' very possible.

However... It probably won't be necessary. `Long` can hold numbers as large as 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, so you usually can simply use `Integer` or `Long` for storing any numbers you can calculate.

Comment: the wrapper class of char is Character and it is not sub class of  Number

Comment: what is your main target? Why do you need to do that?

Comment: Why don't you want to include float and double? What should do your program if a Float is provided?

Comment: Honestly, I think you’d be better off making one method that accepts a `long`.  Values of all the other integral types can be passed to it without a cast;  Java will automatically promote them, since there would be no loss of information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to realize this behaviour at compile time.

You can specify multiple type bounds in Java – for example `T extends Integer & Long` – but that means that `T` has to extend *both*  `Integer` and `Long`.

Other languages – for example [Ceylon](http://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.2/tour/types/) – know the concept of type unions like `Integer|Long|Char`, but Java does not.

A possible workaround would be to use `Number` as a type bound and manually check the type at runtime, or to duplicate the public interface for the allowed types (e. g. write `someMethod(Integer)` and `someMethod(Short)` that call a private method that accepts a `Number`).  Anyway, think twice whether you really need this restriction.